# Serialization delimiter in Ruby

Tags: ruby, serialization

I'm writing a `serialize` method that converts a Tree into a string for storage. I was looking for a delimiter to use in the serialization and wasn't sure what to use.

I can't use `,` because that might exist as a data value in a node. e.g.

```
  A
 / \
B   ,
```

would serialize to `A, B, ,,` and break my `deserialization` method. Can I use non-printable ASCII characters, or should I just guess what character(s) are unlikely to show up as input and use those as my delimiters?

Here's what my `serialize` method looks like, if you're curious:

```
def serialize(root)
  if root.nil?
    ""
  else
    root.val + DELIMITER + 
      serialize(root.left) + DELIMITER + 
      serialize(root.right)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several common methods I can think of:

- Escaping: you define an escape symbol that "escapes" from the "special" interpretation. Think about how `\` acts as an escape character in Ruby string literals.
- Fixed Fields / Length Encoding: you know in advance where a field begins and ends. (Fixed fields are basically a special-case of length encoding where you can leave out the length because it is always the same.)

Example for escaping:

```
def serialize(root)
  if root.nil?
    ""
  else
    "#{escape(root.val)},#{serialize(root.left)},#{serialize(root.right)}" # using ,
  end
end

private def escape(str) str.gsub('\', '\\').gsub(',', '\,') end
```

Example for length encoding:

```
def serialize(root)
  if root.nil?
    "0,"
  else
    "#{root.val.size},#{root.val}#{serialize(root.left)}#{serialize(root.right)}" # using length encoding
  end
end
```

Any `,` you find within `size` characters belongs to the value. Fixed fields would basically just concatenate the values and assume that they are all the same fixed length.

You might want to look at how existing serialization formats handle it, like [*OGDL: Ordered Graph Data Language*](http://ogdl.org/), [*YAML: YAML Ain't Markup Language*](http://yaml.org/), [*JSON*](http://json.org/), [*CSV (Character-Separated Values)*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180), [*XML (eXtensible Markup Language)*](https://w3.org/XML/).

If you want to look at binary formats, you can check out [Ruby's `Marshal` format](http://jakegoulding.com/blog/2013/01/15/a-little-dip-into-rubys-marshal-format/) or [ASN.1](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_Syntax_Notation_One).

Your idea of finding a seldom-used character is good, even if you use escaping, you will still need less escaping with a less used character. Just imaginee what it would look likee if 'ee' was the eescapee characteer. However, I think using a non-printable character goes too far: unless you *specifically* want to design a binary format (such as Ruby's Marshal, Python's Pickle, or Java's Serialization), "`less` debuggability" (i.e. debugging by simply inspecting the output with `less`) is a nice property to have and one that you should not give up easily.

Comment: Thanks! What are your thoughts on the use of non-printables?

Comment: Your idea of finding a seldom-used character is good, even if you use escaping, you will still need less escaping with a less used character. Just imaginee what it would look likee if 'ee' was the eescapee characteer. However, I think using a non-printable character goes too far: unless you *specifically* want to design a binary format (such as Ruby's Marshal, Python's Pickle, or Java's Serialization), "`less` debuggability" (i.e. debugging by simply inspecting the output with `less`) is a nice property to have and one that you should not give up easily.